# ASP.NET MVC5 Display data to user with specific selected data"Branch"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have table with the next columns

```
Id,Name,A_Status,BranchName.
```

Would be that expendiently to achive, with the next method, i described bellow?
Column branch has 25 different names. So, i want to create a page, with 25 titles of branch(and for each, create his own cshtml page), where user can enter and view data of that specific branch, he has chosen. On each of those pages specific permissions, not all users can enter and view them.
I decided to achive it with the next code.

My controller

```
public ActionResult A_Branch ()
        {
            string query = "SELECT BranchName,Name, MAX(A_STATUS) AS A_Status "
                    + "FROM Students "
                    + "WHERE BranchName= '1_Branch' "
                    + "GROUP BY BranchName,Name";
            IEnumerable<EnrollmentStudentGroup> data = db.Database.SqlQuery<EnrollmentStudentGroup>(query);

            return View(data.ToList());
        }
```

And the next actionresult which i'm going to create 23 times more.

```
public ActionResult B_Branch ()
            {
                string query = "SELECT BranchName,Name, MAX(A_STATUS) AS A_Status "
                        + "FROM Students "
                        + "WHERE BranchName= '2_Branch' "
                        + "GROUP BY BranchName,Name";
                IEnumerable<EnrollmentStudentGroup> data = db.Database.SqlQuery<EnrollmentStudentGroup>(query);

                return View(data.ToList());
            }
```

My 2 models;

```
public class Student : BaseEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }           
        public string BranchName { get; set; }                         
        public string Name { get; set; }                    
        public int A_Status { get; set; }


    }
public class EnrollmentStudentGroup
    {

        public string BranchName { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int A_Status { get; set; }


        public IEnumerable<EnrollmentStudentGroup> StudentCollection { get; set; }
    }
```

and my Model

```
 public class Model
    {
        public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
        public List<EnrollmentStudentGroup> EnrollmentStudentGroup { get; set; }
    }
```

My newest controller ( after " .select " he is giving me errors )

```
   [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult TestNew(string branchname)
        {
            // check stuff like permissions
            var db = new MovieContext();
            var model = new Model();

            var students = db.Student
                .Where(x => x.BranchName == branchname)
                .GroupBy(x => new { x.BranchName, x.Name, x.Currency, x.NoCart, x.NoAccount })
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    BranchName = x.FirstOrDefault().BranchName,
                    Name = x.FirstOrDefault().Name,
                    A_Status = x.Max(p => p.A_Status),
                    Currency = x.FirstOrDefault().Currency,
                    NoCart = x.FirstOrDefault().NoCart,
                    NoAccount = x.FirstOrDefault().NoAccount
                }).ToList();
            foreach (var item in students)
            {
                model.Students.Add(new Student
                {
                    A_Status = item.A_Status,
                    BranchName = item.BranchName,
                    Name = item.Name,
                    NoAccount = item.NoAccount,
                    NoCart = item.NoCart,
                    Currency = item.Currency

                });
            }
            return View(model);

        }
```

Now that error, i updated my model and view(cshtml) by your answer.
[image]

My view(cshtml)

```
@model Tessa.Models.Model

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "BranchView";
}

<h2>BranchView</h2>

@foreach (var item in Model.Students)
{
    <p>@item.Name</p>
    <p>@item.A_Status</p>
    <p>@item.BranchName</p>
    <p>@item.NoAccount</p>
    <p>@item.NoCart</p>
    <p>@item.Currency</p>
}
```

Comment: Crazy! Don't even think about it. You have one method and pass a parameter to it to indicate which data you want to return. And you can check what permissions the current user has to determine what should be displayed

Comment: if the user can choose the branch name, then supply the branch name as a parameter (perhaps the user can choose via a dropdownlist?) to your action method and then supply that value as a parameter to your query. Then you use the same view and action method every time to get the data. Having 25 near-identical methods is insane and misses one of the basic points of programming - i.e. accepting and using user input to change the code's behaviour. Besides that, if someone adds another branch to the table you don't want to have to write yet more code to access it, that way lies madness.

Comment: @ADyson Hello, i implemented method in answer bellow, now my step is to give one user an permission to view, for example branch with name "Branch_1"(localhost/students/Test01/Branch_1) right ?

Comment: @whitefang if you have a new question, please ask a new question. Comments are not the place for discussion of new features you want to add to your code. Ask a new question, showing what you've done so far and what issue precisely you're facing. Thankyou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in the comments wrote you dont have to do this for every single branch. Here is a solutions which may help you

Your Controller

```
        public ActionResult Branch(string branchname)
    {
        var db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var model = new Model();

        var students = db.Students
                                  .Where(x => x.BranchName == branchname)
                                  .GroupBy(x => new { x.BranchName, x.Name, x.Currency, x.NoCart, x.NoAccount })
                                  .Select(x => new
                                  {
                                      BranchName = x.FirstOrDefault().BranchName,
                                      Name = x.FirstOrDefault().Name,
                                      A_Status = x.Max(p => p.A_Status),
                                      Currency = x.FirstOrDefault().Currency,
                                      NoCart = x.FirstOrDefault().NoCart,
                                      NoAccount = x.FirstOrDefault().NoAccount
                                  }).ToList();

        foreach (var item in students)
        {
            model.Students.Add(new Student
            {
                A_Status = item.A_Status,
                BranchName = item.BranchName,
                Name = item.Name,
                NoAccount = item.NoAccount,
                NoCart = item.NoCart,
                Currency = item.Currency
            });
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

So you only pass the branchname to the controller. Her are severale diffrent ways to do this.

Its good practice to have a model to pass to a view.

```
public class Model
{
     public List<Student> Students { get; set; }

    //Some other propertys

    public Model()
    {
        Students = new List<Student>();
    }
}
```

And finialy you can write your view like this

```
@model TestApp.Models.Model 

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "BranchView";
}

<h2>BranchView</h2>

@foreach (var item in Model.Students)
{
    <p>@item.Name</p>
    <p>@item.A_Status</p>
    <p>@item.Branchname</p>
    <p>@item.NoAccount</p>
    <p>@item.NoCart</p>
    <p>@item.Currency</p>
}
```

In the `foreach`-loop you can do normal html stuff. This will done for every element in your list.

I hope this help you.

Comment: I stucked ) with your controller ) dont know )

Comment: Error on word after new "Model"  var model = new Model

Comment: The type or namespace name 'Model' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @whitefang you need to create a new Class normaly you call it something which end with the prefix Model. For example EnrollmentStudentGroupsModel or somehting like this. In the example i only give the name model.

Comment: I did next ( var model = new EnrollmentStudentGroup )

Comment: Now he is giving me error for the next field (  "  x.BranchName.First(), " )

Comment: Error CS1061 'IGrouping<<anonymous type: string BranchName, string Name, string Currency, string NoCart, string NoAccount>, Student>' does not contain a definition for 'A_Status' and no extension method 'A_Status' accepting a first argument of type 'IGrouping<<anonymous type: string BranchName, string Name, string Currency, string NoCart, string NoAccount>, Student>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @whitefang the problem is that your database model dont have a column A_Status. I take the proberty from you question but of course you can use your query to. But the benefit of Entity Framework is that you have typesafty even by writing the query.

Comment: @whitefang sorry was my fault i update my complett anwser.

Comment: thanks controller now is working, but cshtml page giving me the next error ( i updated thread with error )

Comment: @whitefang I have update my Model and my View, I used the old name in the view sorry for that.

Comment: now another error ( added to thread ), I updated model and view by ur answer.

Comment: @whitefang in your model the ctor is missing for creating the list. And where do you make a dictonary?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174860/discussion-between-darem-and-white-fang).